# Wrong Date values with Apache Phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix

I'm sending data from Spark to Apache Phoenix via JDBC. The phoenix field where I send the data is of type (Phoenix) Date. When I was testing it, I saw that the dates that Spark was sending were recorded in Phoenix with some errors.

After that I opened the container where I am executing Phoenix, and I tried to query directly in Phoenix (by hand) with some test values and I saw the same errors continued happening so it wasn't a parsing/casting problem.

I appreciate it is happening when I write a date before the year 1500. Phoenix is limited to this date?

The screenshot below shows this behavior.

[image]

Anyone knows why this behavior?

Comment: What exactly is the error ?

Comment: @vmaroli The day of the date are wrong in all the upserts before the year 1500

Comment: Are you observing the error before year 1500 or year 1582 ? October month of 1582 doesn't have dates from 5th to 14th because of a correction made. But that only impacts those 10 days, not all dates before that.

Comment: before 1500. In the picture you can see when I insert a date lower than 1500, the stored date has a wrong day.